# Seeking ArcGIS Pro SDK equivalent to geometry.measureOnLine(point) of ArcPy?

Tags: c#, geometry, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am looking for a method in the ArcGIS Pro SDK 2.2 that will return the measure distance along a given polyline geometry.

Here is the python method

```
 measure = polylineGeometry.measureOnLine(pointGeometry)
```

Comment: Esri says `GeometryEngine.QueryPointAndDistance` "... also calculates related items."  ... did you try it to see if it calculates an M ? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/api-reference/#topic20292.html

Answer (score 1):

The QueryPointAndDistance3D works great here is the Meth

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ArcGIS.Core.CIM;
using ArcGIS.Core.Data;
using ArcGIS.Core.Geometry;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Contracts;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Dialogs;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Threading.Tasks;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping;

namespace MTools
{
    internal class StationFeatures : Button
    {
        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            StationFeature();
        }
        public async void StationFeature()
        {
            await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
            {
                MapView mapView = MapView.Active;
                var listFeatureLayers = mapView.Map.Layers.OfType<FeatureLayer>()
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(x => x.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint);
                var centerline = mapView.Map.Layers.OfType<FeatureLayer>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == LayerModel.LayerName.ToString())
                    .First();
                FeatureClass fcLine = centerline.GetFeatureClass();
                QueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilter()
                {
                    WhereClause = "OBJECTID IS NOT NULL"
                };
                using (RowCursor linecursor = fcLine.Search(queryFilter, true))
                {
                    while (linecursor.MoveNext())
                    {
                        using (Feature lineFeature = (Feature)linecursor.Current)
                        {
                            Polyline centerpolyline = (Polyline)lineFeature.GetShape();
                            foreach(var pointFeatureLayer in listFeatureLayers.ToList())
                            {
                                FeatureClass pointFc = pointFeatureLayer.GetFeatureClass();
                                FeatureClassDefinition pointFcDef = pointFc.GetDefinition();
                                IEnumerable<Field> fields = pointFcDef.GetFields().Where(x=>x.Name=="MEAS_STATION");
                                if (fields.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    using(RowCursor featurecursor = pointFc.Search(queryFilter, true))
                                    {
                                        while (featurecursor.MoveNext())
                                        {
                                            using (Feature pointFeature = (Feature)featurecursor.Current)
                                            {
                                                double distanceAlongCurve, distanceFromCurve;
                                                AsRatioOrLength asRatOrLen = AsRatioOrLength.AsLength;
                                                SegmentExtension extension = SegmentExtension.NoExtension;
                                                MapPoint featurePoint = (MapPoint)pointFeature.GetShape();
                                                MapPoint mPoint = GeometryEngine.Instance.QueryPointAndDistance3D(centerpolyline, extension, featurePoint, asRatOrLen, out distanceAlongCurve, out distanceFromCurve);
                                                MessageBox.Show(distanceAlongCurve.ToString());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```